# Making a counter that increases if value in previous column is different but resets when other column value changes?

Tags: python, pandas

I am making a counter column that increases only when the values at (i-1) are different than that of (i), but it resets when user_id changes.

Input:

```
user_id sc_id
1         100
1         100
1         101
1         102
2         100
2         101
3         101
3         103
```

Below is my code:

```
df['subcat_counter'] = 1

for i in range(1,len(df)):
    if df.sc_id[i-1]==df.sc_id[i] and df['user_id'][i-1]==df['user_id'][i]:
        df.at[i,'subcat_counter']=df.subcat_counter[i-1]
    else:
        df.at[i,'subcat_counter']=df.subcat_counter[i-1]+1
```

Below is the desired output:

```
user_id sc_id   subcat_counter
1         100    1
1         100    1
1         101    2
1         102    3
2         100    1
2         101    2
3         101    1
3         103    2
```

Comment: What is the problem? What is your desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can `groupby` with `cumcount` and before that drop duplicates so each same, `user_id` and `sc_id` get the same `subcat_counter`. After that we `fillna` with `forwardfill (ffill)`:

```
df['subcat_counter'] = df.drop_duplicates(['user_id', 'sc_id'])\
                       .groupby(['user_id'])['sc_id']\
                       .cumcount()+1

df.fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)

print(df)
   user_id  sc_id  subcat_counter
0        1    100             1.0
1        1    100             1.0
2        1    101             2.0
3        1    102             3.0
4        2    100             1.0
5        2    101             2.0
6        3    101             1.0
7        3    103             2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way using `groupby`

```
df['subcat_counter'] = (df.groupby('user_id')['sc_id']
                          .transform(lambda x: x.diff().gt(0).cumsum() + 1))
```

Output:

```
   user_id  sc_id  subcat_counter
0        1    100               1
1        1    100               1
2        1    101               2
3        1    102               3
4        2    100               1
5        2    101               2
6        3    101               1
7        3    103               2
```